# Autohotkey script making keys "sticky"

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I've been successfully using an AHK script for almost a year which maps Ctrl-C and Alt-E-S-V (an Excel shortcut) to Win-key combinations, and maps Ctrl-Del to Ctrl-Space, Ctrl-- (delete row).

However, occasionally (and more and more frequently), the computer thinks that the Win or Ctrl key is still held down. I've spent a long time looking for a fix and nothing has worked for me, including various script rewrites and uninstalling and reinstalling AHK.

Here's my script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

;map ctrl-c, ctrl-v, and ctrl-e-s-v (paste values) to win-key combos
#a::Send ^c
#s::Send ^v
#q::Send !e,{s},{v}{Enter}

*CapsLock::Send {Media_Play_Pause}
Return  ;disable CapsLock permanently

;map win-x to ctrl-alt-/ - shortcut to open 'everything.exe', then close it automatically when it's not in focus
#x::
Send ^!/
Sleep, 1000
WinWaitNotActive, ahk_class EVERYTHING
WinClose, ahk_class EVERYTHING
return

;win-z to prt scn
#z::Send {PrintScreen}

;map ctrl-del to select whole line and delete it
~^Del::
Send +{space}
Send ^-
Send {Left}
return
```

Edit: [this person](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/88715-control-key-getting-stuck/) had the same problem as me, though none of the fixes suggested in that thread helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No telling if this will fix the problem, but you can try this script.

```
; Always run your script as admin
if not A_IsAdmin
{
   Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"  ; Requires v1.0.92.01+
   ExitApp
}
#SingleInstance, Force
#NoEnv
SetBatchLines, -1
SetKeyDelay, 50

;There's a command for disabling CapsLock permanently
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff 

return

$#a::^c
$#s::^v
$#z::PrintScreen
$#q::SendEvent, ^!v!v{Enter}
$#x::
    Send ^!/
    Sleep, 1000
    WinWaitNotActive, ahk_class EVERYTHING
    WinClose, ahk_class EVERYTHING
return

$~^Del::SendEvent, +{space}^-{Left}
```

Tested all the rempas (except win+x) and they seem to be working just fine. I haven't been able to duplicate the modifier problem you're having.

Let me know if this solved hte problem. If not, we can try to adjust fire.

Comment: Thank you - above and beyond what I was looking for! I've applied your changes and run as admin, and so far the bug isn't re-occurring. Still curious as to what specific change causes the bug, something for a rainy day I guess.

Comment: No clue what was causing the bug, but you're definitely not the first person I've seen post that problem. I'm usually over on the [AHK subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/) answering questions like this.

If this didn't work, next step would've been forcing the up state of whatever keys were acting up. ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯ I'm just glad to hear everything is working like you intended.

Comment: @GroggyOtter – maybe if you can lose a word on which part of the code can possibly make the difference and why.